# How can I convert an AVI file to FLV format with PHP?

Tags: php, flv, avi

Is it possible to convert an AVI file to FLV format with PHP? If so, how? I don't need a complete solution, just a hint on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffmpeg` is a great library for this sort of thing. Here's a walkthrough of the process:

http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to convert the video into Flash video and just use one of the many Flash video players out there. There is also an [ffmpeg api](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php) for PHP, this would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have ffmpeg installed, you can do this:

```
<?php
   define('FFMPEG_LIBRARY', '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ');
   $exec_string = FFMPEG_LIBRARY.' -i inputfile.avi outputfile.flv';
   exec($exec_string);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a command line transcoder like `Mencoder` or `vlc`. Alternatively, look for a PHP library which allows you to access a library like `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

Try FFmpeg. Check the [link](http://ffmpeg.org/)