# Video conversion through PHP any format to mp4?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i convert a file from avi to flv with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571134/how-can-i-convert-a-file-from-avi-to-flv-with-php)

Hello guys ,
             Can u help me to convert a video from any format to wmv format through PHP

Comment: make up your mind!! MP4 or WMV?

Comment: The title is inconsistent with the question... do you want to convert to WMV or mp4? *EDIT* ninja'd

Comment: You don't use PHP. You use external tools which happen to get invoked via a PHP script.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the right version installed (find a statically linked binary):

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.flv output.wmv");
```

You might need some extra parameters (audio bitrate etc.). But you can use [WinFF](http://winff.org/) to find out (shows the exact command IIRC).

Answer (score 3):

Call `mencoder` from PHP.  There are lots of docs out there on the appropriate command line flags to `mencoder` in order to get it to output your desired format.

```
$output = exec('mencoder -of lavf -o file.mp4 --lots-of-other-options');
```

If you are using PHP variables from user input in your command line string, be sure to call `escapeshellarg()` on them first.